# Blake-256 genesis block generation helpint

Tags: hash, merkle-tree, genesis-block

I'm making my own coin and get problem to generate genesis for my fork.

Genesis need to be blake-256. I was found this git https://github.com/lhartikk/GenesisH0 and tryed to use this script, i also added that hashing algo to my linux systyem. 
https://github.com/ocminer/decred-hash

Main problem that i need to include to generation 2 additional parameters, which are not included to that script. That is extrannonce and nversion.

Hope somebody can assist me with that. In that case bounty on coins start is guaranted.